# How to override Refit's implementation of an interface method?

Tags: rest, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient, refit

I recently discovered the convenience of using [Refit](https://github.com/reactiveui/refit), but after reading through its documentation I was unable to find a way to replace/override an implementation of an interface method that `RestService` would normally generate.

Does Refit provide a way to do this? Or is there a way to solve such a problem without getting too hacky?

I'm just worried about using Refit all over the place and then half way into a project realizing I can't modify the implementation of a method. It's inevitable that I'll have to break coding standards to meet a requirement and I'd like to know what would be the solution if a situation like this occurs?

Answer (score 0):

Its not exectly what you want, but you can create extension where you call Refit implementation, but before and after call you can add any customization you want.
For example, I have use it to reformat response.

Answer (score 0):

Now in .Net8, you can now use DIM (default-interface-method) to handle this. I'd prefer to use the following (also found in the link shared in reference) for more control over the service I required from IoC.

```
public interface ICustomerApi
{
  [Get("/customer/{id}")]
  public Task<Person> Get([AliasAs("id")] int id);
}

public interface IDecoratedCustomerApi
{
  Task<Person> Get(int id);
}

public class DecoratedCustomerApi(ILogger<DecoratedCustomerApi> logger, ICustomerApi customerApi) : IDecoratedCustomerApi
{
  public async Task<Person> Get(int id)
  {
    logger.LogInformation($"Requested Id: {id}");
    var customer = await customerApi.Get(id);
    logger.LogInformation($"Customer", customer);
    return customer;
  }
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/reactiveui/refit?tab=readme-ov-file#default-interface-methods